# How to join tables based on certain condition? SQL

Tags: sql

There are three tables `A`,`B`,`C`

Table `A` has columns `[ID], [flag], [many other columns]`

Table `B` has columns `[ID], [column subset of Table A]`

Table `C` has columns `[ID], [same column subset as Table B (thus also a subset of Table A), however with different values]`

I want to join Table `A` & Table `B` if `Flag = '1'`, and want to join Table `A` & Table `C` if `Flag ='2'`

Could you help me how I might be able to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  (If you have a choice, I recommend SQL Sever over MS Access ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're looking for a [`UNION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
SELECT
  <interesting columns>
FROM
  A
  JOIN
  B
  ON A.ID = B.ID 
  AND A.Flag = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
  <exactly the same interesting columns>
FROM
  A
  JOIN
  C
  ON A.ID = C.ID 
  AND A.Flag = 2
```

If the flag is really a string column, put the single quotes back. If it's numeric, leave them out.

Since the flag field in `A` should effectively eliminate duplicates between the result sets, I opted for `UNION ALL`, which is more efficient than `UNION` because `UNION` will run a `DISTINCT` under the covers, which in this case is likely unnecessary.

Comment: Anybody understand the downvote? I can be talked into deleting or editing.

Comment: Thanks @EricBrandt for your answer. It worked exactly as proposed in your answer, many thanks!

Comment: @Dev_Operator, I'm glad it helped! Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left and/or upvoting. It rewards me with some reputation points, and you get some, too. [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)